# mdadm: faulty Array, how to get recover as much as possible?

Tags: linux, raid, data-recovery, mdadm

I have a RAID5 with 4 Disks in my PC. All of them were healthy (and the RAID itself) until before.

I tried to install windows 8.1 which automatically creates this "SystemReserved"-Partition. The Installer decided a good place to put that partition without asking the user, is on one of the RAID-Devices. (Don't even gonna start ranting...)

So im stuck with:
3 RAID-Devices which are completely fine. (As far as I think, and theoretically makes sense)
1 RAID-Device which has a partition-table and a NTF partition with 350MB.

What I did was:
Set said disk to "faulty"

```
   mdadm -f /dev/md0 /dev/sdc
```

Removed said disk of raid

```
   mdadm -r /dev/md0 /dev/sdc
```

Then I tried to delete the partition with the help of gparted so its back to "unused space" as I don't have a partition on these disks. Which at first looked fine.

Removed the superblock so it looks like a new drive

```
    mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc
```

Then I added the disk back into the RAID

```
    mdadm --manage -a /dev/md0 /dev/sdc
```

checking the /proc/mdstat it seemed that everything was back to normal and it's syncing the sdc.

But when trying to mount i get:

```
    mount: Stale NFS file handle
```

dmseg tells me:

```
    EXT3-fs (md0): error: get root inode failed
```

now I fired up gparted again and weird enough: sdc still has this 350MB partition. Also when I look up the md0-RAID gparted has a partition:
        /dev/md0p1 (unknown filesystem, 350MB)

The rest is marked as unallocated.

There is very precious data ( personal data from childhood and stuff ) on it and I would be sooo happy not to lose that.
So you might understand that I'm currently way to scared to do anything on my own...
I now set the sdc back again to faulty, so atleast i still can keep most of the data left on 3 devices...

My question:
Any ideas why the md0 now has a partition? that shouldn't happen right? because that was on sdc ONLY, and not on the whole raid and windows was not able to see the RAID, just the single devices.
Second question: How can I fix this? I mean any ideas on how to proceed to lose as minimum as possible?

If you need any logs or more information, just ask!
Thanks a lot already!

EDIT:
output of /proc/mdstat:

```
 Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
 md0 : active raid5 sdd[1] sdc[4](F) sde[3] sdf[2]
  4395415488 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [_UUU]

 unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: I think it's time to restore from your backups.

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`

Comment: sadly no backups, /proc/mdstat is in original post as EDIT.

Comment: Obligatory reminder that **RAID is not backup**. RAID allows you to remain operational in the face of certain types of hardware failures, but it is not a form of backup.

Comment: Is this hardware or software RAID?  Now if you have 3 working disks out of 4 with RAID 5 you **should** be able to rebuild.  If it is hardware RAID 5 you should be able to replace the faulty disc and the RAID controller should automatically rebuild it.  Partition is irrelevant to a RAID.  Otherwise try RStudio demo(has limitations) and if it works get the full version.  You will need some place to migrate the data to so buy extra hard drives.